# apply layer mask to all layers?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, masking

How do I apply a layer mask to every layer in my movie?
After I highlight all of the layers and put them in the layer mask, the layers that are in folders will not go in the layer mask.

Comment: you get one mask per movie clip, so an option would be to nest all the movieclips you want to apply the mask to into one clip and apply the mask to that. sounds like an Flash IDE/superuser question.

Comment: But I only have one movie clip.  I just used the folders for organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sad thing is that you can't mask folders in CS4, nor in CS5 you just need to move the layers. Only options is making one movieclip with all the folders and masking that one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what I did was since I was done with my movie, I converted each of the folders into normal layers and then the mask applied to everything.

Thanks though for the answers :]

Answer (score 0):

Right click the layers you want to mask and then click properties -> masked